# JOOQ codegenerator Indexes

Tags: jooq

when use jOOQ's code generator, it will split nested classes to prevent large static initialisers, and the `Indexes.java` maybe contains nested classes such as  `Indexes0`, `Indexes1`...

I use generator with `<version>3.12.3</version>`, it generates two nested classes `Indexes0` and `Indexes1`, `Indexes0` contains 501 indexes, `Indexes1` contains 264 indexes.

but use `<version>3.13.4</version>`, it only generates `Indexes0` nested classes, contains 387 indexes.

Is this a bug in jOOQ generator? or I need to add other config？

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ 3.13 introduced a new `<includeSystemIndexes/>` defaulting to false, see [#9601](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9601). This flag turns off the generation of code for system-generated indexes, i.e. indexes you wouldn't want to get declared explicitly when calling [`Meta.ddl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html#ddl()) on your generated code.

If you want those indexes to be included, just turn the flag back on. However, I doubt you need them.